# Can i put a value inside a ReactJS Component and then get that value somewhere in another file with importing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i am making a ReactJS Component for a contact form. And right now I want to make a method that gets the value from an input in the JSX, and then i want to get the value that that method returns from outside the component, in another file. Is this possible?

My component file:

```js
//Inporting React.
import React from 'react';

//Creating the contactForm Component
class ContactForm extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.props.submit} className={this.props.formclass} id={this.props.formid}>
                <div className='inputDiv'>
                    <input type="text" name="nameinput" placeholder="Name" id={this.props.nameinputid} className={this.props.nameinputclass} />
                    <input type="email" name="emailinput" placeholder="Email" id={this.props.emailinputid} className={this.props.emailinputclass} />
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" name="subjectinput" placeholder="Subject" id={this.props.subjectinputid} className={this.props.subjectinputclass} />
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" name="messageinput" placeholder="Message" id={this.props.messageinputid} className={this.props.messageinputclass} />
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" className={this.props.submitbtnclass} id={this.props.submitbtnid}/>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

ContactForm.defaultProps = {
    submit: "sendEmail()",
    formclass: "formClass",
    formid: "formId",
    nameinputid: "nameInputId",
    nameinputclass: "nameInputClass",
    emailinputid: "emailInputId",
    emailinputclass: "emailInputClass",
    subjectinputid: "subjectInputId",
    subjectinputclass: "subjectInputClass",
    messageinputid: "messageInputId",
    messageinputclass: "messageInputClass",
    submitbtnclass: "submitBtnClass",
    submitbtnid: "submitBtnId"
}

export default ContactForm
```

The file where i want to get the value:

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import ContactForm from './contactForm.js'


function App() {
  return (
    <ContactForm />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your parent component to have access to the value of a variable within the child component, consider [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the parent component.

Suppose the value you want access to in your parent component is the user's name, which is entered in `ContactForm`. To implement this, first initialize the variable as a state variable in your parent component:

`const [name, setName] = useState('')`

[useState docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Then, pass the necessary values to your child component as props:

`<ContactForm name = {name} setName = {setName} />`

[Components and props docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

In your child component, destructure props:

`const { name, setName } = props`

Finally, in your child component, change the `form`'s onSubmit to call `setName` with the user's input.